# PHP DomDocument Save XML with HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, domdocument, entities

How would I save an XML file opened with DomDocument so that the HTML inside won't be encoded into HTML entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, read through it however you normally are going to, then use html-entity-decode()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

in whatever you are using to write it back out as xml.